# Validar numero de caracteres do username

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte validação para o username:

```
if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
  $nameErr = "Username:Escolha um username.";
} else {
  $uname = test_input($_POST["username"]);
  $v1 = 'ok';
  if (!ereg("(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z\_0-9\.-]*))$", $_POST["username"])) {
    $v1 = 'ko';
    $nameErr = "Username:Somente letras e números.";
  }
}
```

Desta forma consigo validar com sucesso um username que contenha letras ou numeros ou se o campo estiver em branco. Mas como faço para conseguir validar o numero de caracteres?

Comment: usa maxlength, o atributo do html

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues hum.. aí o cara tira pela ferramentas do desenvolvedor, e a validação vai pro espaço.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters exatamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para limitar o número de caracteres você pode usar o atributo `maxlength` na input;

```
<input maxlength="7">
```

Mas você pergunta como validar o números de caracteres, então...
Você pode fazer uma contagem do conteúdo da input usando a função [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strlen.php).
Segue um exemplo abaixo:

```
$max = 7;
$validar = strlen($_POST["username"]);

if ($validar > $max) {
    return FALSE;
}
else {
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Eu usaria o `mb_strlen` ;). Só uma dica.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters se a página estiver em ISO-8859-1 pode dar problemas. Principalmente se pegar caracteres como "Ç","Ã", etc. que serão interpretados como UTF-8

Comment: @Bacco é complicado isso. Se o `username` for só ascii, então tá de boa, né.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters o ideal seria o Chris avisar na resposta que se a codificação for UTF, usar mb_strlen, se for ISO-8859-1 ou similares, usar strlen :) - Quanto ao HTML5, acho complicado não ter um "minlength" nativo.

Answer (score 0):

Com maxlength você pode limitar direto no html.

**Exemplo:**

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="5">
```

Comment: Fácil ^^ Muito obrigado, não me lembrei dessa propriedade. resolveu.